# Set scale dependant labels arcmap 10.3

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, labeling, scale, vbscript

I am wondering if it is possible to create scaled labels so that at a certain zoom level only one label appears but when you zoom in closer more labels appear for different fields.

I have this VBScript expression to allow for multiple fields to appear in labels (This is what I would like to see at a zoomed in level e.g at 1:10,000 (my layer consists of large polygons fyi))

**Function FindLabel ( [Name], [Kvalue], [Pvalue], [LimeRequirement], [PHvalue] )
  FindLabel = "Plot Name: " & [Name]&vbnewline & "K Value: " & [Kvalue]&vbnewline & "P Value: " & [Pvalue]&vbnewline & "Lime Requirement: " & [LimeRequirement]&vbnewline & "pH : " & [PHvalue]
End Function**

Output of expression:

**Plot Name: Balally Park**

**K Value: 1.76**

**P Value: 5.97**

**Lime Requirement: 4.37**

**pH : 5**

At a zoomed out level (from 1:500,000 to 1:10,000) I would just like Plot name and K value.

Is there a way of doing this without creating copies of the layer and setting scales on the layer itself?

Comment: Duplicate of http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/74642/ but I like the wording and example here better so I'm not flagging it as such. Also *related* to http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/100155/ but note that is actually a different question. The currently upvoted answer duplicates the answer here but is incorrect in actually addressing that particular question (which is about maintaining a label size at changing scales).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Arc 10.3 you can access the [Maplex Labeling Engine](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#/A_quick_tour_of_labeling_with_the_Maplex_Label_Engine/00s800000054000000/) which gives you much more control over labels.

In the image below showing a layer properties you can select: *define classes of features and label each class differently*

You can then set a scale range for each grouping, so for example you'd set the range to 1:500,000 to 1:10,000 and put you vb script to just show Name and K value in the Expression tab. Then for your second group set the scale to >1:500,000 and add all of the VB script above.

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much! That was very simple but was not documented anywhere I looked!

Comment: @RobO'Loughlin (and MAJ742), it is true Maplex gives much greater placement control over labels, but it is *not* required to use label classes - you can create them with the standard labeling engine as well.